# UILabel text alignment when English and Hebrew mixed as text?

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, hebrew

I have `UILabel` which having a text which is mixed of English and Hebrew. I wanted to alignment as per language means for English `LTL` and for Hebrew `RTL`.

Text is

> I bless You, God, for creating the fruit of the vine:
>
> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶֽלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי
>   הַגָּֽפֶן.

Comment: Try with `NSAttributedString`, setting a `NSParagraphStyle` and then `[yourLabel setAttributedText:theAttributedString]`

Comment: NSAttributedString not able to set Alignment property. any working code. That would help me a lot.

Comment: Do you have at least a text sample? The alignement is set in the `NSParagraphStyle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample you could be inspired with.

Note: I don't know how you create your all text, so I don't know how you'll know what's in English or what in Hebrew, but you'll get the idea.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I bless You, God, for creating the fruit of the vine:\n בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶֽלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הַגָּֽפֶן."];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *englishParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[englishParagraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *hebrewParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[hebrewParagraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

NSRange englishRange = NSMakeRange(0, [@"I bless You, God, for creating the fruit of the vine:" length]);
NSRange hebrewRange = NSMakeRange([@"I bless You, God, for creating the fruit of the vine:" length],
                                  [[attrStr string] length] - [@"I bless You, God, for creating the fruit of the vine:" length]);

[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                value:englishParagraphStyle
                range:englishRange];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                value:hebrewParagraphStyle
                range:hebrewRange];

[myLabel setAttributedText:attrStr];
```

You also may want to do this before setting it to your `UILabel`:

```
[attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                value:[UIFont whateverFontWithWhateverSize]
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])];
```

Comment: Great solution, though you could create 2 labels that everyone of them will contain different language.