# How to align English and Arabic text in one UITextView correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, uitextview, text-alignment

I have a `UITextView` which contains both Arabic and English text.

[image]

What happens is that both texts get aligned according to the UITextView alignment as follows:

[image]

Aligning left: all left

Aligning center: all center

Aligning right: all right

Aligning justify: all left

Aligning ---: all left

Now: What can I do to make Arabic text align right and English text align left where they are in the same `UITextView`

Note: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239812/swift-textview-align-with-english-and-arabic-languages) question which has the same problem but nobody answered.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The Arabic text maybe included between two English texts and vice versa.

For example:

> The is some text
>
> اهلا بكم
>
> More English text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456260/uilabel-text-alignment-when-english-and-hebrew-mixed-as-text/24456612 ?

Comment: that's helpful but the problem is that I don't know objective-c

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString`, `NSMutableParagraphStyle` both should be available in Swift. Just follow the methods and the classes, search them in the documentation, they exists in Swift.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MS73Ckss ?